# Metaio SDK: problems setting up a new project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, metaio, junaio

I'm trying to setting up a new project using Metaio SDK but i have a few problems with this.

First of all i've followed the tutorial of this website, but it ended up not working. (http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/ios/creating-a-new-ar-application/index.html)

I've been trying to do it with objective C or with Swift with an Obj-C bridging file.

This is what i've done:

-DL `metaioSDK.framework` and add to project

-Add other frameworks:
[image: other frameworks]

-Import metaioSDK (in view controller or in bridge)

```
#import <MetaioSDK/MetaioSDKViewController.h>
```

-Add subclass in ViewController (`MetiaoSDKViewController`)
Just like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: MetiaoSDKViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

---

-This images show the errors i'm getting:

[image: Errors resume]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Apple solved the problem for you. They bought Metaio and are closing shop.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you're getting are coming from c++ code being compiled with the Swift compiler.

You should change it to Obj-C++. Either you change the file extension of your ViewController from 'm' to 'mm' (obj-c++) or change the compile-settings to compile your whole project as Obj-C++.

Answer (score 0):

In the Metaio tutorial which I assume you're following, they have a spelling error in subclassing MetaioSDKViewController since Metaio is spelt Metiao. So all you need to change is that line.